# Overlaying two geom_contours with specified breaks shows incorrect line types

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, contour

Reproducible R code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(metR)
v <- reshape2::melt(volcano)
g <- ggplot(v, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value), color = "white", size = 1.25,
               breaks = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value, linetype = ifelse(value <= 130, "solid", "dash")),
               color = "black", size = 0.45,
               breaks = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190),
               show.legend = F) +
  geom_text_contour(aes(z = value))
g
```

When I overlay a `geom_contour` with a white background and another `geom_contour` with an `ifelse` function for different line types depending on value, the plotting procedure shows broken contours, close to the specified ifelse value of 130, as shown in the plot below.

[image: contour plot]

Can someone recommend a solution? I suspect it has to do with the interpolation method.

Reproducible code **without** the `metR` library (used to plot contour labels on above plot)

```
library(ggplot2)
v <- reshape2::melt(volcano)
g <- ggplot(v, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value), color = "white", size = 1.25,
               breaks = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value, linetype = ifelse(value <= 130, "solid", "dash")),
               color = "black", size = 0.45,
               breaks = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190),
               show.legend = F)
g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, there is no way to use `ifelse` successfully with the `geom.contour` function. The correct usage is by plotting both contours individually. Please note that the error is purely caused by your `ifelse` function, not by *overlaying* two plots, as you assumed in your title.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
v <- reshape2::melt(volcano)
g <- ggplot(v, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value, linetype = "solid"),
               color = "black", size = 0.45,
               breaks = c(140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190),
               show.legend = F) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value, linetype = "dashed"),
               color = "black", size = 0.45,
               breaks = c(100, 110, 120, 130),
               show.legend = F)
g
```

[see plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odc0m.png)

Generally, `ifelse` can be used in ggplot2 to specify aestetics, however, for correct display the values to be displayed need to be unambiguous.

When plotting contours `ggplot2` bins the data and generates continious lines within breaks that are then classified using the specified aestetic. Your `ifelse` operation overwrites these classification leading to either potential lines sharing both solid and dashed aestehtics (not displayed), or only partial solid/dashed aestetics (interrupted).

This becomes more obvious if you round your data (in alignment with your bins) in your `ifelse`. As you can see interrupted lines are not an issue anymore, however, the bigger gap between the two classes is still present.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
v <- reshape2::melt(volcano)
g <- ggplot(v, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value, linetype = ifelse(round(value,-2) <= 130, "solid", "dash")),
               color = "black", size = 0.45,
               breaks = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190),
               show.legend = F)
g
```

[see plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkXLi.png)

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense about the rounding. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel dumb. A simple work around is to simply plot two separate `geom_contour` with specified values, like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
v <- reshape2::melt(volcano)
g <- ggplot(v, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value), color = "white", size = 1.25,
               breaks = c(100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value, linetype = "solid"),
               color = "black", size = 0.45,
               breaks = c(140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190),
               show.legend = F) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value, linetype = "dashed"),
               color = "black", size = 0.45,
               breaks = c(100, 110, 120, 130),
               show.legend = F)
g
```

[image]

But, I still wonder if there is a way to do this successfully with the `ifelse` function?